# Null Form Data Post WKWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, wkwebview

I have no idea for null `form data` in WKWebView for first loading in 2 requests:

1. **Got redirect** from another website with request to `doku_payment/redirect` with `form data` (**null**, POST method) and then
   redirect to second request
2. Request to `salesorder/xxxxxx`

I run in Chrome Desktop is fine, like on picture:
[image]

In WebView Android is fine for loading the requests.

How can I solve the problem?

env:
Xcode v. 10.0

Comment: in 2nd loading its fine ?

Comment: May i know your url require cookies ?

Comment: In 2nd loading is error, because 1st loading is error for null form data.
In the picture above, I run them in chrome desktop..

Yes, I run with cookies..

@ShauketSheikh

Comment: Please check your cookies are not gonna be synced , you can check in image that you pasted there are no cookies. you must sync your cookies with wkwebview before loading.

Comment: I have synced the cookie in decidePolicyFor function, and there is no problem with the cookie, in WKWebView has been tested for some features...

Comment: Cookies should be sync before load request not in decidePolicyFor

Comment: I got redirect from another website, how can I set cookie before webView.load?

And, in decidePolicyFor: 1. I put the cookie if not exists; 2. load again the request; 3. handler(.cancel)

@ShauketSheikh

Comment: depends if you are using multiple instance of wkwebview then you need to sync cookies everytime, if one instance then you can set cookie before load webview, like implement a closure after closure completion make load request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180712/discussion-between-shauket-sheikh-and-rudi-wijaya).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem..

In `decidePolicyFor` function, DO NOT add any value to the header, just `completionHandler(.allow)` for path that post form data.

So, I need add the logic for allowing the path that posting form data

Comment: This does not work for me. Can you show a more complete example?